# I want to have an image align left with the text in the <h1> tags below but am trouble finding a solution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, vs-web-site-project

I need to have a second image align left of the  text but layered on top of the background image. I am having some trouble figuring out what css I need to make this work. Currently everything I have tried messes with the text positioning or the background image.

Luckily, this is a personal project so there is no timeline but I would appreciate any help that could be given.

I just started learning web development this past year so it all still feels a little new to me.

```
.hero-full-container {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative
}

.background-image-container {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%
}

.white-text-container h1 {
    color: #fff
}

.overlay-gradient {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 0, transparent 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 0, transparent);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#4D000000", endColorstr="#00000000", GradientType=0)
}

.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px
}

.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px
}

.col-xs-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px
}

 .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33333%
}

 .col-md-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333%
}

.hero-full-wrapper .text-content {
    padding-top: 30%
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-full-container background-image-container white-text-container" style="background-image:url('./assets/images/home_01.jpg')">
  <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="hero-full-wrapper">
          <div class="text-content">
            <h1>William</h1>
            <h1>Mark</h1>
            <h1>Derichsweiler</h1>
            <!--<p>Lorem ipsum</p>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't undestand very well your question, but if you want to have a background image and another image above this image, you can do this creating more `div`. Once you insert a background image, you can insert another div inside this div, e.g. :

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="second-image">
        <img src="link_to_your_image">
    </div>
    <div class="text-area">
        <h1>William</h1>
        <h1>Mark</h1>
        <h1>Derichsweiler</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the for css, you can use `flex` property, setting the direction to `flex-direction: row`, e.g. :

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('link_to_your_image');
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.second-image, .text-area {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

I hope this can help you, have a nice day.